# How to make get and patch requests on a json file using Angular?

Tags: json, angular, get, httprequest, patch

Hello I have a json file on a server and I want to make a get request, take the values and then make a patch request.

My json file:

```
 post:[
{
    "report":"1",
    "park":"1",
    "use":"7",
    "group":"60",
    "privateplin":"30",
    "privateplus":"30",
    "commonprivateplus":"15",
    "ownerfirst":"30",
    "ownersecond":"-20",
    "ownerthird":"-50",
    "first":"30",
    "second":"30"
  }
]
```

My service.ts

```
export class AppServices{


constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient) {
    
}

public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
    
    const httpOptions = {
    
    };
    
     return this.httpclient.get("https://socialpark.upatras.gr/final/final.json").pipe(
        catchError(this.errorHandler));

           

 }
 
 public postJSON(fin:any): Observable<any> {
   
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        }),
      };
       return this.httpclient.patch<any>("https://socialpark.upatras.gr/final/final.json",fin,httpOptions).pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));

 }
 errorHandler(error:any){

    return Observable.throw(error || 'Backend Server Err');
   
 }
```

}

My component.ts :

```
    export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  report:number;
  park:number;
  use:number;
  group:number;
  privateplin:number;
  privateplus:number;
  commonprivateplus:number;
  ownerfirst:number;
  ownersecond:number;
  ownerthird:number;
  first:number;
  second:number;
  fin:any;
  constructor(private appService: AppServices){}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.getJSON().subscribe(

      data=>{
           this.report=data.report
           this.park=data.park 
           this.use=data.use
           this.group=data.group
           this.privateplin=data.privateplin
           this.privateplus=data.privateplus
           this.commonprivateplus=data.commonprivateplus
           this.ownerfirst=data.ownerfirst
           this.ownersecond=data.ownersecond
           this.ownerthird=data.ownerthird
           this.first=data.first
           this.second=data.second
      },
      error => {
        window.alert("Δεν μπορούν να πρβληθούν οι ισχύοντες πόντοι");
      console.error(error);
      },
    );
  }

  set(preport,ppark,puse,pgroup,pprivateplin,pprivateplus,pcommonprivateplus,pownerfirst,pownersecond,pownerthird,pfirst,psecond){
        let report=preport.value;
        let park=ppark.value;
        let use=puse.value;
        let group=pgroup.value;
        let privateplin=pprivateplin.value;
        let privateplus=pprivateplus.value;
        let commonprivateplus=pcommonprivateplus.value;
        let ownerfirst=pownerfirst.value;
        let ownersecond=pownersecond.value;
        let ownerthird=pownerthird.value;
        let first=pfirst.value;
        let second=psecond.value;

        this.fin={
          "report":report,
          "park": park,
          "use": use,
          "group":group,
          "privateplin":privateplin,
          "privateplus":privateplus,
          "commonprivateplus":commonprivateplus,
          "ownerfirst":ownerfirst,
          "ownersecond":ownersecond,
          "ownerthird":ownerthird,
          "first":first,
          "second":second        
      };

      this.appService.postJSON(this.fin).subscribe(response=>{

        window.alert("Επιτυχής ανανέωση στοιχείων");


      },
      error => {
        
        console.error(error);
        
      },
      );


  }
  
}
```

The problem may be on the service.ts with the url. Please help me
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: You need a webserver to handle this, you cannot directly write to a remote file just like that

Comment: @David Angular code and json file are both on the same server

Comment: It does not matter where it is. Angular is a client side fremework. If you make a http request to write to a file, you need a webserver (nodejs/php/java..) able to receive that request and write to the file

Comment: @David May installing a json server on the global server solve the problem?